# Отлов события создания окна в Xlib

Tags: c, xlib

Здраствуйте, я хочу написать себе оконный менеджер, а точнее уже пишу с использованием xlib.

Документацию активно читаю, уже кое что смог зделать(перемешение окон за мышкой при удержании клавиши и некоторые другие мелочи) но не как не пойму как мне зделать например рамку вокруг окна и кнопочку закрыть, в документации не обясняеться как мне поймать окно и "протюнинговать" его своей рамкой и кнопочкой, исходники других оконных менеджеров смотрел но код большинства из них немного сложноват мне, самый понятный это dwm, но он тайловый, поэтому не все мне там подходит

Может есть статья "создание оконного менеджера" где-то или может мне кто-то подсказать как мне словить создание окна и цеплять к нему свои прибомбасы?

Comment: Перефразируйте поконкретнее, с кодом

Comment: Куда конкретней? Я хочу сделать вокруг окон рамку и сверху еще кнопку закрыть, мне не понятно как это делаеться, код чего? У меня есть код только инициализации и перемешения окон, я не думаю что он тут уместен

Comment: По правилам вы должны продемонстрировать усилия для самостоятельного решения проблемы, и вопрос должен быть конкретным

Comment: В конце текста вопроса я задал конкретный вопрос "как мне словить создание окна и цеплять к нему свои прибомбасы?"

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Александр, зачем же так грубо с новичками )

Comment: @NickVolynkin. это я скопировал откуда-то, не разглядев, что ссылка не на *google*, а на *lmgtfy*. // но в конце отображается именно то, что просил автор вопроса — статья о том, как написать *window manager*.